# RelatedObjectDoesNotExist at /accounts/google/login/callback/ User has no userprofile

Tags: django, django-allauth

Django-allauth is working fine for signups on my app, when users choose Facebook and Twitter. But when users choose Google, the following error is raised:

**RelatedObjectDoesNotExist at /accounts/google/login/callback/ User has no userprofile**

**userprofile** is a Model that extends **User** Model (One to One relation), and is created for each user when the signup happen. It looks like the userprofile model is not being created for Google signups, but I could not understand why..

My code is:

```
     *views.py*

     # This view creates and populates profile with social data
     @receiver(user_signed_up)
     def populate_profile(request, user, sociallogin=None, **kwargs):

         if sociallogin:
             if sociallogin.account.provider == 'facebook':
                 if not user.first_name and          sociallogin.account.extra_data['first_name']:
                     user.first_name = sociallogin.account.extra_data['first_name']
                 if not user.last_name and sociallogin.account.extra_data['last_name']:
                     user.last_name = sociallogin.account.extra_data['last_name']
                 if not user.email and sociallogin.account.extra_data['email']:
                     user.last_name = sociallogin.account.extra_data['email']
                 user.save()
                 try:
                     userprofile = sociallogin.user.userprofile
                 except:
                     userprofile = UserProfile(user=sociallogin.user)

                 userprofile.facebook = sociallogin.account.get_profile_url()
                 userprofile.save()

             if sociallogin.account.provider == 'twitter':
                 if not user.first_name and sociallogin.account.extra_data['name']:
                     name = sociallogin.account.extra_data['name']
                     user.first_name = name.split()[0]
                 if not user.last_name and sociallogin.account.extra_data['name']:
                     name = sociallogin.account.extra_data['name']
                     user.last_name = name.split()[1]
                 if not user.email and sociallogin.account.extra_data['email']:
                     user.last_name = sociallogin.account.extra_data['email']
                 user.save()
                 try:
                     userprofile = sociallogin.user.userprofile
                 except:
                     userprofile = UserProfile(user=sociallogin.user)

                 userprofile.twitter = sociallogin.account.get_profile_url()
                 userprofile.save()

             if sociallogin.account.provider == 'google':
                 if not user.first_name and sociallogin.account.extra_data['given_name']:
                     user.first_name = sociallogin.account.extra_data['given_name']
                 if not user.last_name and sociallogin.account.extra_data['family_name']:
                     user.last_name = sociallogin.account.extra_data['family_name']
                 if not user.email and sociallogin.account.extra_data['email']:
                     user.last_name = sociallogin.account.extra_data['email']
                 user.save()

                 try:
                     userprofile = sociallogin.user.userprofile
                 except:
                     userprofile = UserProfile(user=sociallogin.user)

                 userprofile.google = sociallogin.account.get_profile_url()
                 userprofile.save()




    *my_adapter.py*

    from allauth.account.models import EmailAddress
    from allauth.socialaccount.adapter import DefaultSocialAccountAdapter

    from django.contrib.auth.models import User

    from user_profile.models import UserProfile

    # This adapter creates an account or connects the social account to an existing account
    class SocialAccountAdapter(DefaultSocialAccountAdapter):
        def pre_social_login(self, request, sociallogin):

            user = sociallogin.user
            perfil = UserProfile(user=sociallogin.user)
            perfil.save()

            # Ignore existing social accounts, just do this stuff for new ones
            if sociallogin.is_existing:
                return

            # some social logins don't have an email address, e.g. facebook accounts
            # with mobile numbers only, but allauth takes care of this case so just
            # ignore it
            if 'email' not in sociallogin.account.extra_data:
                return

            # check if given email address already exists.
            # Note: __iexact is used to ignore cases
            try:
                email = sociallogin.account.extra_data['email'].lower()
                existing_user = User.objects.get(email__iexact=email)
                perfil = existing_user.userprofile
                email_address = existing_user.email
                #email_address = EmailAddress.objects.get(email__iexact=email)

            # if it does not, let allauth take care of this new social account
            except User.DoesNotExist:
                return

            # if it does, connect this new social login to the existing user
            user = existing_user
            sociallogin.connect(request, user)
```

Comment: Could you provide stack trace?

Comment: Do you mean the error? Here it is: http://bit.ly/1ODQCe3

Comment: Did you get an answer for this? :(

Comment: Check the auth related table: `account_emailaddress`, your user id should have a corresponding entry there.